# Rudin: Showing at least one of the trichotomy holds for dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha ,\beta$ be dedekind cuts, define $\alpha < \beta$ to mean $\alpha$ is a proper subset of $\beta$.

It is clear from the definition of proper subset that at most one of:
$\alpha < \beta$, $\alpha = \beta$, $\alpha > \beta$ can hold.

But we also need to show at least one of the 3 cases must hold to finish trichotomy proof. Rudin only seems to proves that if $\alpha < \beta$, $\alpha = \beta$ are both false, then $\alpha > \beta$ case must be true. This I understand why.

The problem is what if $\alpha > \beta$, $\alpha < \beta$ are false, how to we prove $\alpha = \beta$? He didn't tell the reader to try it themselves, so I'd assume it's really obvious but I can't think of an obvious reason.

The approach I have is first to show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ cannot both have elements exclusive to the other set otherwise it contradicts definition of dedekind cuts, then naturally I'd get $\alpha \subset \beta, \beta \subset \alpha$ so $\alpha = \beta$. Is this a valid way to prove this?

Because Rudin didn't include it, is there a trivial reasoning I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ \alpha = \beta $ was false, you would get a contradiction. This is because you would have $ \alpha < \beta $ and $ \alpha = \beta $ false. You have proven that this implies $ \alpha > \beta $. In terms of logic showing that $ \neg p $ and $ \neg q $ imply $ r $, is equivalent to showing that one of $ p, q $ and $ r $ is true.